Why the gas cost strangely so big when deploy
Description
Why deploy the code failed. The error log is as following:
gas 1000000000000000000 gas
transaction cost    984375000000005328 gas 
execution cost  984374999999815072 gas 

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.

why the gas cost so big?
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Uniswap {
    string[] public tokens = ["CoinA", "CoinB", "CoinC"];
    mapping(string => ERC20) public tokenInstanceMap;
    uint256 ethValue = 100000000000000;

    constructor() {
        for (uint i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            CustomToken token = new CustomToken(tokens[i], tokens[i]);
            tokenInstanceMap[tokens[i]] = token;
        }
    }
}

contract CustomToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 10 ** 18);
    }
}


-->
How to locate and fix the problem?
